# Cocossharp Division by Zero Error CCTMXTiledMap

Tags: c#, xamarin

Hi I'm just starting to mess around with Cocossharp and Xamarin.

At the moment I'm trying to load up a tilemap created through Tiled but I keep getting this error when i run this code:

System.DivideByZeroException: Division by zero

```
CCTMXTiledMap tilemap = new CCTMXTiledMap("tilemap.tmx");
```

Any input on why this occurs?

[image]

Comment: I don't see any division by zero. Are you sure you get this error on that line?

Comment: I'll throw up a screenshot ;)

Comment: I think its the way you created or organized your tmx. See reference to something similar here: https://cocos2dxna.codeplex.com/discussions/461037 ... search for divide by zero.